# Using the http.path property in model defintion

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

The model I have created has this url: http://localhost:3000/api/Employees

Now if I set the http property like this: 
"http": {"path": "/foo/mypath"}

http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-Top-levelproperties

What will be the new url to access the model ? I tried various permutations and combinations none of which seem to work.

Comment: Hmm... based on your earlier URL it seems like it should be `/api/foo/mypath` ... it's not that?

Comment: I have tried all of:  /api/foo/mypath, /api/foo/mypath/Employees, /foo/mypath, /foo/mypath/Employees none of which works

Comment: Can you post your model definition file?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, http paths must not start with a leading slash, see https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/pull/573

The following setting should work well

```
"http": {"path": "foo/mypath"}
```

URL:

```
/api/foo/mypath
```